# Faster Approach - Entity Framework Data Transforming

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, t-sql

I have a method I wrote to do the following.

Get orders by week using Id of order get details by OrderDetail table excluding line of detail that are cancelled.

For each of the lines found that aren't cancelled get the ProductNumber and make sure that the product listed is a option for the product and not just a parent product number.

Take the found number and go to another table where it tells me what makes the product and add up everything that it takes to make the product.

Put this number by week into another table.

```
private void ProcessOrders(string[] orders, DateTime weekOf)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> tmpRes = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        using (var context = new AS400_PIM5ContextDataContext())
        {
            context.CommandTimeout = 0;
            foreach (var ord in orders)
            {
                var orderDetails = context.OrderDetails.Where(x => x.OrderNumber.Equals(ord) && (!x.Status.HasValue || x.Status.Value != 'C'));
                foreach (var detail in orderDetails)
                {
                    var sku = detail.ProductNumber.Trim().ToUpper();
                    var squ = detail.SequenceNumber;
                    var realSkus = context.OrderDetailRaws.Where(x => x.SequenceNumber == squ && x.OrderNumber == detail.OrderNumber);
                    foreach (var val in realSkus)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val.RawMaterialSku) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val.RawMaterialSku))
                        {
                            sku = val.RawMaterialSku.Trim().ToUpper();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    var children = GetChildern(sku, context);
                    foreach (var child in children.Keys)
                    {
                        if (child.Equals(sku))
                            if (context.SupplyChain_ComponentPAs.Any(x => x.ProductNumber.Equals(sku)))
                                continue;
                        decimal umo = 0m;
                        children.TryGetValue(child, out umo);
                        if (umo == 0)
                            throw new Exception();
                        if (tmpRes.ContainsKey(child))
                        {
                            int currentUsage = 0;
                            tmpRes.TryGetValue(child, out currentUsage);
                            tmpRes.Remove(child);
                            tmpRes.Add(child, Convert.ToInt32(currentUsage + (umo * detail.Quantity)));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tmpRes.Add(child, Convert.ToInt32(umo * detail.Quantity));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (var key in tmpRes.Keys)
            {
                int outVal = 0;
                tmpRes.TryGetValue(key, out outVal);
                var tmpPre = new SupplyChain_PostMinMax();
                tmpPre.ProductNumber = key;
                tmpPre.Usage = outVal;
                tmpPre.IsWeekly = true;
                tmpPre.ReferenceDate = weekOf;
                context.SupplyChain_PostMinMaxes.InsertOnSubmit(tmpPre);
            }
            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

The above process is very slow and takes 2 days to process 2 years of records. Is there a faster way? Is it possible to write a straight query for this whole process? Is there some entity code modifications I can do to expedite this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a stored procedure on another server. Then used SSIS to migrate data to main server.